# Do the centrioles in the centrosome differ in their angle to one another?

Tags: protein-structure

The centrioles in the centrosome are often shown at an orthogonal angle, does this arrangement differ between samples, as in, does the daughter centriole show up in different sides of the mother centriole, or on the distal end rather than the proximal end?